# How to build ES5 Angular 1.5.x app with webpack 2.x? Getting Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, build, webpack-dev-server, ecmascript-5, webpack-2

Running the `webpack-dev-server` works fine:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --hot
```

But not the build:

```
rm -rf static && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p
```

#### package.json

```
├─ angular-animate@1.5.11
├─ angular-cookies@1.5.11
├─ angular-file-saver@1.1.3
├─ angular-gettext@2.2.1
├─ angular-gravatar@0.4.2
├─ angular-i18n@1.5.11
├─ angular-messages@1.5.11
├─ angular-mocks@1.5.11
├─ angular-resource@1.5.11
├─ angular-sanitize@1.5.11
├─ angular-smart-table@2.1.8
├─ angular-ui-bootstrap@2.3.2
├─ angular-ui-calendar@1.0.2
├─ angular-ui-router@0.3.2
├─ angular@1.5.11
├─ …
├─ webpack-dev-server@2.3.0
├─ webpack@2.2.1
```

#### Webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin = require('html-webpack-harddisk-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
        publicPath: '/static/',
        filename: '[name]-[hash:8].min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.moment': 'moment',
            Util: 'exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src', 'index.html'),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            alwaysWriteToDisk: true
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
            {test: /\.scss$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']},
            {test: /\.html$/, use: ['html-loader']},
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: {
                    host: '0.0.0.0',
                    protocol: 'http:',
                    port: 8000
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

#### app.js

```
'use strict';
var angular = require('angular');
var ngResource = require('angular-resource');
require('angular-ui-router');

angular.module('app', [ ngResource])
.value('User', {})  // global object

require('./services/api.service.js');
require('./services/auth.service.js');
require('./routes.js');
require('./pages/login/login.js');
```

#### Error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
```

#### Question

What is happening? How do I get my build to work?

Comment: The unknown provider is a sign something wasn't included i.e. service, directive or anything else. It can also happen if you use some sort of code mangling/uglifying and don't use the array notation `.directive('myDirective', ['$http', function($http){ } ])`

Comment: @maurycy I don't use the array notation nor Uglify/mangling as for now.

Comment: `Unknown provider: e` judging from this error is either that or you injected `e` in some place where `e` is not available

Comment: In your routes.js are you using some sort of `resolve` for a controller? If so, I think I'm having the same issue. Were you able to solve this one?

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue with `ng-annotate-loader`:

#### Install

```
npm install --dev ng-annotate-loader
```

#### Configure webpack

Add this line to `module.rules`:

```
{test: /src.*\.js$/, use: ['ng-annotate-loader']}
```

#### Full code

Webpack

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin = require('html-webpack-harddisk-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
        publicPath: '/static/',
        filename: '[name]-[hash:8].min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            moment: 'moment',
            'window.moment': 'moment',
            Util: 'exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src', 'index.html'),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            alwaysWriteToDisk: true
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            'node_modules'
        ],
        alias: {
            Services: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/services/')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
            {test: /\.scss$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']},
            {test: /\.html$/, use: ['html-loader']},
            {test: /src.*\.js$/, use: ['ng-annotate-loader']},
            {test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: ['url-loader?limit=8192&mimetype=application/font-woff']},
            {test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: ['url-loader?limit=8192&mimetype=application/font-woff']},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: ['url-loader?limit=8192&mimetype=application/octet-stream']},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: ['file-loader']},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: ['url-loader?limit=8192&mimetype=image/svg+xml']}
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: {
                    host: '0.0.0.0',
                    protocol: 'http:',
                    port: 8000
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Package.json

```
{
    "version": "1.27.5",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rm -rf static && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --display-error-details --progress --hide-modules",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot",
        "test": "node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./karma.conf.js --single-run",
        "test:watch": "node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./karma.conf.js --auto-watch",
        "lint": "xo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.x",
        "angular-animate": "1.5.x",
        "angular-cookies": "1.5.x",
        "angular-file-saver": "1.1.x",
        "angular-gettext": "2.2.x",
        "angular-gravatar": "0.4.x",
        "angular-i18n": "1.5.x",
        "angular-messages": "1.5.x",
        "angular-resource": "1.5.x",
        "angular-sanitize": "1.5.x",
        "angular-smart-table": "2.1.x",
        "angular-ui-bootstrap": "2.3.x",
        "angular-ui-calendar": "1.0.x",
        "angular-ui-router": "0.3.x",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
        "font-awesome": "4.x.x",
        "fullcalendar": "3.x.x",
        "hint.css": "2.4.x",
        "jasmine": "2.5.x",
        "jquery": "3.x.x",
        "moment": "2.x.x",
        "moment-weekday-calc": "1.1.x",
        "tether": "1.x.x",
        "toastr": "2.x.x"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "1.5.x",
        "chai": "3.5.x",
        "chalk": "1.1.x",
        "cross-env": "3.1.x",
        "css-loader": "0.26.x",
        "del": "0.1.x",
        "eslint": "3.x.x",
        "eslint-config-angular": "0.5.x",
        "eslint-plugin-angular": "1.6.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jasmine": "2.2.x",
        "exports-loader": "0.6.x",
        "file-loader": "0.10.0",
        "flatpickr": "2.3.x",
        "html-loader": "0.4.x",
        "html-webpack-harddisk-plugin": "0.0.x",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.x",
        "karma": "1.x.x",
        "karma-chai": "0.1.x",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.x.x",
        "karma-mocha": "1.x.x",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.x",
        "karma-webpack": "2.0.x",
        "mocha": "3.2.x",
        "ng-annotate-loader": "0.2.x",
        "node-sass": "4.5.x",
        "phantomjs-polyfill-find": "ptim/phantomjs-polyfill-find",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.x",
        "sass-loader": "5.x.x",
        "style-loader": "0.13.x",
        "url-loader": "0.5.x",
        "webpack": "2.2.x",
        "webpack-dev-server": "2.3.x",
        "xo": "0.17.x",
        "yargs": "6.6.0"
    },
    "xo": {
        "envs": [
            "browser"
        ],
        "globals": [
            "angular"
        ]
    }
}
```